# Accessing pointer to long long int with subscript

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management

I came across this snippet in a coding contest very recently. Could not figure how does this work. The second line creates a pointer to a **single** long long int.

1. How can we use that with subscript in the `for` loop?
2. Even if that's possible, doesn't it raise segmentation fault upon second iteration?

```
int Q = 3;
long long *queryArray = (long long*)malloc(sizeof(long long));

for(i_queryArray = 0; i_queryArray < Q; i_queryArray++){
    scanf("%lld", &queryArray[i_queryArray]);
}
```

How to interpret this snippet?

Comment: The memory is never accessed

Comment: The code is accessing out of bounds. That is undefined behaviour.  Anything can happen, including it appears to work.

Comment: What's wrong here? downvote!

Comment: 1. If we avoid undefined behaviour, we can't. 2. It might. No guarantees whatsoever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is indeed wrong. It goes out of bounds and writes to indices `[1]` and `[2]`, which don't exist.

Accessing invalid array elements doesn't necessarily result in a segmentation fault. It's undefined behavior, meaning anything can happen (including a crash, corrupting unrelated data, or seemingly working without a problem).

If you're confused about subscripting in general: `a[b]` just means `*(a + b)`. The first iteration is fine because `ptr[0]` is `*(ptr + 0)` is `*ptr`.